# Drupal permissions are not being applied

Tags: drupal

Why are my permissions not being applied?

```
$items['admin/mymodule'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_admin',
    'access arguments' => array("admin mymodule"),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'file' => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
    'title' => 'mymodule',
  );
```

function mymodule_perm(){
  return array("admin mymodule", "earnings_report");
}

When I go to Mysite/admin/mymodule, I am able to access it WITHOUT being logged in.

The permissions on admin/user/permissions are correctly set to only give access to "site developer" and "store administrator", and the anonymous user are not part of those roles.

I tried going to /admin/content/node-settings/rebuild and /admin/build/modules, but it didn't help.

The permission "earnings_report" is working as expected, but "admin mymodule" is not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'access callback' => TRUE,` line defines who can access `admin/mymodule`

You've set it to always be TRUE which means it can always be accessed.  I think you need to change it to something like:

```
'access callback' => 'user_access',
'access arguments' => array('admin mymodule'),
```

Comment: By default, Drupal uses `user_access()` as access callback; there isn't the need to define the access callback, if you are using the default one. The access arguments need to be defined, as there isn't a default value for that.